# How to limit selection of two fields not override other checkbox?

Tags: jquery, html, bootstrap-4

I have created two fields for checkbox, but i am struggling to allow limitation of my checkbox's. What these two does currently they allow selection to be made. But each time when i click the download button. It allows other checkbox to download automatically of which i dont want that its bad for user to see this on front end. Here is my logic below;

```
<!---- Checkbox for selecting it to download. -->
<div class = "custom-control custom-checkbox">
  <input type="checkbox" class ="custom-control-input" id="acceleration">
  <label class = "custom-control-label" for="acceleration">Acceleration</label>
</div>

<!---checkbox for button-state showing on/off when clicked. ---->
<div class ="custom-control custom-checkbox">
  <input type ="checkbox" class="custom-control-input" id="button_state">
  <label class ="custom-control-label" for = "button_state">Button-State</label>
</div>

<!----Download button into CSV file.  --->
<div class="form-group">
  <div class="col-md-1.9 text-center">
    <button id="download" name="download" class="btn btn-warning" >Download</button><br>
  </div> 
</div>
```

Javascript:

```
$(function(){
  $("#download").click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var isAccelerate = ($('#acceleration').is(':checked'));
    var isButtonState = ($('#button_state').is(':checked'));

    if (isAccelerate&&isButtonState) {
      window.open('https://api.thingspeak.com/channels/932891/feeds.csv?api_key=**&start=2019-12-13T00:00+02&end=2019-12-17T23:59+02:00');
    }
    if (isAccelerate){
      window.open('https://api.thingspeak.com/channels/932891/fields/1.csv?api_key=***&start=2019-12-13T00:00+02&end=2019-12-17T23:59+02:00');
    }
    if (isButtonState){
      window.open('https://api.thingspeak.com/channels/932891/fields/8.csv?api_key=***&start=2019-12-13T00:00+02&end=2019-12-17T23:59+02:00');
    }
  });
});
```

JSFiddle: [Link](https://jsfiddle.net/Lt0qw5db/1/)

Comment: The requirement  is not clear

Comment: update your expected case one by one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to Freedomm-m.

```
<div class = "custom-control custom-checkbox">
  <input type="checkbox" class ="custom-control-input" id="acceleration">
  <label class = "custom-control-label" for="acceleration">Acceleration</label>
</div>
<div class ="custom-control custom-checkbox">
  <input type ="checkbox" class="custom-control-input" id="button_state">
  <label class ="custom-control-label" for = "button_state">Button-State</label>
</div>
<div class="form-group"><br>
  <div class="col-md-1.9 text-center">
    <button type="button" id="download" name="download" class="btn btn-warning" >Download</button><br>
  </div> 
</div> 

$(function(){
  $("#download").click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var isAccelerate = ($('#acceleration').is(':checked'));
    var isButtonState = ($('#button_state').is(':checked'));

    if(isAccelerate && isButtonState) {
      window.open('https://api.thingspeak.com/channels/932891/feeds.csv?api_key=**&start=2019-12-13T00:00+02&end=2019-12-17T23:59+02:00');
    }else{
      if(isAccelerate){
        window.open('https://api.thingspeak.com/channels/932891/fields/1.csv?api_key=***&start=2019-12-13T00:00+02&end=2019-12-17T23:59+02:00');
      }
      if(isButtonState){
        window.open('https://api.thingspeak.com/channels/932891/fields/8.csv?api_key=***&start=2019-12-13T00:00+02&end=2019-12-17T23:59+02:00');
      }
    }
  });
});
```

DEMO: [LINK](https://jsfiddle.net/Lt0qw5db/3/)

Comment: Thanks mates, it works they way i wanted it, no overriding of any download, when both being checked.

Answer (score 0):

If you step through your code manually you get:

1. if first and second checked open feeds.csv
2. if first ticked open 1.csv
3. if second ticked open 8.csv

which you can see, if first and second checked, you get all three, if you only want one, your logic would be:

1. if first and second checked open feeds.csv
2. if first but not second ticked open 1.csv
3. if second but not first ticked open 8.csv

you *could* change your code to this:

```
if (isAccelerate && isButtonState) {
  window.open("feeds.csv");
}
if (isAccelerate && !isButtonState) {
  window.open("1.csv");
}
if (isButtonState && !isAccelerate) {
  window.open("8.csv");
}
```

or you can add an `else` after the first test:

```
if (isAccelerate && isButtonState) {
  window.open("feeds.csv");
}
else {
  if (isAccelerate) {
    window.open("1.csv");
  }
  if (isButtonState) {
    window.open("8.csv");
  }
}
```

as, in the else, we already know it's not both, you don't need an else for the second.

alternatively, you can just put else in front of each to ensure only one condition is met:

```
if (isAccelerate && isButtonState) {
  window.open("feeds.csv");
}
else if (isAccelerate) {
  window.open("1.csv");
}
else if (isButtonState) {
  window.open("8.csv");
}
```